# jQuery.ajax replace PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to update a REST search result with ajax to not reload a new page.

right now search result is shown within:

```
<div id="searchtable"><?php include 'hotels/hotelList.php';?></div>
```

On click on button I want to reload this div element so it includes a new php file.

Button:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">LOAD</button><br /><br />
```

jQuery

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  $.get( "/hotels/hotelSortBy.php" );
  $('#searchtable').replaceWith('<?php include 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php';?  >');
 }
</script>
```

I'm not able to replace the div element "searchable" - with replaceWith - Am I doing this right ?

Comment: Once javascript is loading, you can't execute PHP. By the time javascript is loading, PHP has finished executing and you're in the user's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for inline PHP if you're using AJAX. Try using jQuery's `.load` AJAX method:

```
function myFunction() {
  $('#searchtable').load('/hotels/hotelSortBy.php');
}
```

Note that this is slightly different than [`.replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) -- using [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) will preserve `#searchtable` and put the new content inside of it, rather than replacing it.

Comment: `'hotels/hotelSortBy.php'` and `'/hotels/hotelSortBy.php'` are not the same thing.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw You don't know that.

Comment: If we're being pedantic, I'll rephrase: "It is foolish to assume that A and B are the same".

Comment: Why is it foolish? It's more likely that it's intentional, given that PHP is traversing the file system instead of the web server.

Comment: @Blazemonger, if the page executing his script was at the url `place.com/some/path`, then the two are most certainly different, and it is not a safe assumption. What I am *not* saying is that absolute paths are worse, but that assuming that a relative path is relative to the www root is never a safe bet.

Comment: It is when they have names as unusual as `hotels/hotelSortBy.php`

Comment: This actually work really good, just remember to use `encodeURI()` when you have space in file name

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding a key element here. Your javascript is running on the client side, while the php runs on the server side (at least usually). Javascript doesn't interpret php and php doesn't interpret javascript either (except json). What you probably want to do is an ajax request to call the url that serve this php file, so that your webserver interpret php and return a response. Check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ probably?

Answer (score -2):

Try using .html instead of replaceWith.

So it would look like

```
function myFunction(){
$('#searchtable').html('<? php include 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php'; ?>');
}
```

Comment: You still can't execute php code after javascript has loaded.

Comment: Better to use ajax if you want to execute php codes after javascript has been loaded. Or the worst thing is to reload the whole page again after replacing the html.